# SQL Server: when to create more than one fulltext catalog

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I'm new to Fulltext indexing in MS SQL Server. I could not find an answer to this question: Would you add several tables to one fulltext catalog, or would you create a catalog for each one? What is the criteria for this decision and how do you measure the catalog's performance/load, etc?
Thanks!